# Is there a way to capture memory usage of a specific android app using appium

Tags: android, performance, memory-management, appium

I am using Appium to automate a hybrid Android app. I am always running my script on an actual Samsung device (galaxy tabs 3 and 4). I want to capture this app's memory usage at various points during script run. For example, I want to capture the memory right after login, then while performing a search in the app and then while the camera opens up in the app etc.

Currently, I am using TeamViewer to manually look at the memory being used while the script is running. I want to be able to capture this programmatically. Is there a way to do that in Appium?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is not built in tool in appium that programmatically shows the device memory consumption. I would suggest consider [AppThwack](https://appthwack.com/) as the possible integrated solution. However it's not free.